# JS stack of callbacks

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of `n` functions that all take a callback, how can I create a queue/stack system where the first function in the array calls the next in its callback?

My work so far.. I am stuck at the logic for the stack.

```
function foo(callback){
  if(callback){
     console.log("calling callback")
     callback();
  }
}

let queue = [foo, foo, foo];

let stack = [];
let i = 0;


// should be equivalent to
foo(foo.bind(null, foo.bind(null, foo)));
```

Comment: I believe you can cleanly do what you want with chaining promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then but that would require you to rewrite your functions to return promises.

Comment: intersting question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is the best way to do it, but it can be done using a simple for loop that runs 1 iteration less than the array size.

```
function foo(callback){
  if(callback){
     console.log("calling callback")
     callback();
  }
}

let queue = [foo, foo, foo];
for(let i=0; i<queue.length-1; i++){
    queue[i](queue[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really await the previous functions if they're asynchronous (and that's probable as callbackifying a synchronous function doesn't make too much sense). Just try to replace `callback()` with `setTimeout(callback,1000)` to see the results...

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question so maybe:

```js
queue.forEach((func, i) => {
  if (queue[i+1]){
    stack.push(func(queue[i+1]))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[foo1,foo2,foo3].reduceRight((callback,func)=>
  ()=>func(callback),
  ()=>console.log("end")
)()
```

Where `foo1`,`foo2`,`foo3` are functions such that each of them accept a callback.

The result will be (when `foo1`,`foo2`,`foo3` are the same `foo` function from your example):

```
calling callback
calling callback
calling callback
end
```

---

#### Explanation

To implement it, I had to iterate from the last function in the array to the start and in every iteration, I build the **next callback for the function in the next iteration**.

The result of `reduceRight` is a function because in each iteration, I build a new function (which, again, is the callback for the "previous" function in the array).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduceRight` to create a callback-chain.

The following function takes the queue as its parameter, and returns the chain as a callback-based, reusable function. When it's called, the chain is executed:

```js
function foo(callback){
  if(callback){
    console.log("calling callback")
    callback();
  }
}

const callbackChainer = queue => callback => queue.reduceRight((acc, elem) => elem.bind(null, acc), callback)()

let queue = [foo, foo, foo];

const chain = callbackChainer(queue)

chain(() => console.log('done'))
/*
calling callback
calling callback 
calling callback 
done
*/

//Reuse chain (without callback):
chain()
/*
calling callback
calling callback
*/
```